# How to make an explosion in pgzrun python?

Tags: python, pgzero

I'm trying to make an explosion in Python by pgzrun. Note that my files are in the right folders

This is my code:

```
from pgzrun import *
from pgzhelper import *
from random import *

TITLE = "title"
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 800

level = 1
lives = 3
score = 0

player = Actor("player2", (300, 580))
enemies = []
bls = []
ebls = []
i = 0
exl = []

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill("skyblue")
    player.draw()
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()
    for bl in bls:
        bl.draw()
    for ebl in ebls:
        ebl.draw()
    for explode in exl:
        explode.draw()
    draw_text()

def update():
    move_bl()
    move_enemy()
    create_ebl()
    move_ebls()
    check()

def remove(list: list, item):
    try:
        list.remove(item)
    except Exception:
        pass

def move_enemy():
    global score
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.x += enemy.vx
        if enemy.x > WIDTH or enemy.x < 0:
            enemy.vx = -enemy.vx
            animate(enemy, duration = 0.1, y = enemy.y + 60)
        for bl in bls:
            if bl.colliderect(enemy):
                remove(enemies, enemy)
                remove(bls, bl)
                score += 1
                sounds.explode.play()
        if enemy.colliderect(player):
            die()

def move_bl():
    for bl in bls:
        bl.y -= 6
        if bl.y < 0:
            remove(bl, bls)

def create_ebl():
    if randint(0, 100 - level * 6) == 0:
        enemy = choice(enemies)
        ebl = Actor("enemy_fire", enemy.pos)
        ebls.append(ebl)

def move_ebls():
    global lives
    for ebl in ebls:
        ebl.y += 10
        if ebl.colliderect(player):
            remove(ebls, ebl)
            lives -= 1
            if lives == 0:
                die()
            else:
                sounds.mat_mang.play()

def check():
    global level
    if len(enemies) == 0:
        level += 1
        create_enemies()

def draw_text():
    screen.draw.text("Level: " + str(level), (0, 0), color="red")
    screen.draw.text("Score: " + str(score), (100, 0), color="red")
    screen.draw.text("Lives: " + str(lives), (200, 0), color="red")

def create_enemies():
    for x in range(0, 600, 60):
        for y in range(0, 200, 60):
            enemy = Actor('enemy_plane', (x, y))
            enemy.vx = level * 2
            enemies.append(enemy)
create_enemies()

def die():
    info = {
        "Level": level,
        "Score": score,
    }
    with open("score.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(info) + ",\n")
    sounds.thua.play()
    exit()

def move_player(key):
    if key == keys.LEFT:
        player.x -= 30
    elif key == keys.RIGHT:
        player.x += 30
    elif key == keys.UP:
        player.y -= 30
    elif key == keys.DOWN:
        player.y += 30

def on_key_down(key):
    if key == keys.SPACE:
        bl = Actor("bullet", pos=(player.x, player.y))
        bls.append(bl)
        sounds.ban.play()
    move_player(key)

go()
```

I have tried to add an Actor to the code but it does not show. I did a lot of research but I found nothing. If the plane is shot, it will explode for around 0.1s and hide. Can you help me?